# Is this a valid JSON response?

Tags: json, security, rest

G'day gurus,

I'm calling the REST APIs of an enterprise application that shall remain nameless, and they return JSON such as the following:

```
throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';
{
  "data": ... loads of valid JSON stuff here ...
}
```

Is this actually valid JSON?  If (as I suspect) it isn't, is there any *compelling* reason for these kinds of shenanigans?

The response I received from the application vendor is that this is done for security purposes, but I'm struggling to understand how this improves security much, if at all.

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Comment: What is value of the `Content-type` header in the response?

Comment: They *might* be doing it so that a service which just eats JSON data from a URL dies when it touches this, with the expectation that the correct script would remove the first line then treat the rest as JSON... Not that I condone that kind of behavior ;)

Comment: Yeah that was my assumption too Thomas, though that argument just doesn't hold water.  What's to stop the client from stripping the first line (as the vendor recommends), then eating the JSON data the same (presumably dangerous) way?!?   I just don't get it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to

http://jsonlint.com/

It is not.

Something like the below is.

```
{
    "data": "test"
}
```

Are they expecting you to pull the JSon load out of the message above?

Comment: Yeah - the recommendation was to strip the first line out prior to parsing the JSON. Apparently they do this to avoid browser-side JS from simply "eval'ing" the returned JSON string or something.  Doesn't hold water imvho...

Answer (score 3):

Its not a JSON format at all. From your question it seems you are working with enterprise systems like JIVE :). I am also facing same issue with JIVE api. This is the problem with their V3 API. Not standard , but following thing worked for me. (I am not sure if you are talking about JIVE or not)

```
//invalid jason response... https://developers.jivesoftware.com/community/thread/2153  
 jiveResponse = jiveResponse.Replace
 ("throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';",String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a valid reason for this: it protects against CSRF attacks. If you include a JSON url as the target of a `<script>` tag, then the same-origin policy doesn't apply. This means that a malicious site can include the URL of a JSON API, and any authenticated users will successfully request that data.

By appropriately overriding `Object.prototype` and/or `Array.prototype`, the malicious site can get any data parsed as an object literal or array literal (and all valid JSON is also valid javascript). The `throw` statement protects against this by making it impossible to parse javascript included on a page via `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely NOT valid JSON. Maybe there's an error in the implementation that is mixing some kind of debug output with the correct output?

And, by no means this is for security reasons. Seems to me this is a plain bug.

Comment: This is coming from a GA version of the application.  :-(

Comment: That was my initial thought too Diego, but when I chased it up with their support personnel they came back with this (specious, it seems) security argument.  I thought maybe I was having a bad IQ day...

Answer (score 0):

`throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';` is certainly not valid JSON.

What MIME type is reported?

Comment: The Content-type header on the response is "application/json", so the application appears to think it's returning valid JSON.

Comment: In that case it's a bug. Security is no excuse for not following standards and, as you say, it makes no sense from a security perspective anyway. Point them towards http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt.

Comment: Thanks for the link Stu - will send it on in due course, though I have no illusions of changing their minds.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they have added that line to prevent JSON Hijacking. Something like that line is required to prevent JSON Hijacking only if you return a JSON array. But they may have added that line above all of their JSON responses for easier implementation.

Before using it, you have to strip out the first line, and then parse the remaining as JSON.

Comment: Which of course defeats the whole purpose - a naive implementation would simply strip the first line then "eval" the rest anyway.  "You can't stop stupid", but what you can do is not irritate the non-stupid by deliberately violating a spec...